# Is there a way to Force 24 fps on Animation Playback?

Tags: animation, timeline

I have some animations and baked simulations in my scene. When I view the playback, it plays at around 16 fps. Right now I can use my mouse to scrub through the timeline which works ok, but obviously I can't move at an exact speed. I know there are ways to improve the fps, but is there a way to simply force 24 fps? I don't care how bad it looks and I don't care if it skips every other frame. I just want to see how the animation looks in real time.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't describe your scene, so there is little to go by. The trick is in optimizing playback as much as possible, try solid shading or wireframe, disable subsurf temporarily (or set the number of subdivisions to a lesser number), set the display of particles to a lesser number and physics to a rough subdivision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly found an answer to this while looking for something else completely unrelated.

[Settings to make viewport playback drop frames in order to keep up with actual animation speed?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220239/settings-to-make-viewport-playback-drop-frames-in-order-to-keep-up-with-actual-a)

Answer (score -1):

I can see the problem here. It is probably because your hardware isn't able to handle it. I am sorry to say that. Maybe try restarting your computer, or try clearing any junk files, anything to increase the speed of your computer. If you could share your computer specs, it would be easier, or there is one more solution, try removing 1 simulation. This might boost your computer. It would be easier if you could share a video of the simulation in the viewport mode along with your hardware specs.

Cheers,
Aster17

Comment: I'm running on an intel core i7-8700 with a GeForce GTX 1070 and 16 GB of RAM. If I turn off everything except a simulation I can get 24 fps, but if I try to see the big picture it slows down

Comment: Well, then it only means that you have too many simulations, try lowering the number. Are you rendering in cycles or Eevee? If cycles, are you rendering in GPU or CPU?

Comment: Cycles, GPU, I know if I remove simulations it will speed up. I was just wondering if there was a way to brute force it like when you drag the cursor along the timeline

Comment: Ok, so is it slow while in the viewport mode, or while rendering, or is the rendered video slow ?

Comment: Look, if it is slow for some reason in the viewport, or if it is slow while rendering, it isn't a problem. But if the rendered video is 16 fps, then there's an issue. If it is either of the first 2, you shouldn't be worried. Simulations in cycles in the viewport are always slow. You could use Eevee to  view the sim in 24 fps. While rendering, the frames will be slow. If it is slow while rendering, then put it in the comments.

Comment: If you are only rendering a video, slow fps in viewport and slow fps while rendering shouldn't be an issue. But if you are creating a video tutorial, then it might be an issue while showing the scene in viewport, while it is being rendered, you could edit that part out while you have completed the tutorial.

Comment: The rendered video is perfectly fine. My questions was just if there was a way to force 24 fps in the viewport. I believe there should be some way to do it(maybe with python?) because dragging through the timeline manually provides an ok result

Comment: you should probably then add a few more frames to the simulation. like 40 more frames to all the simulations. Then you might get a good result. But, what kind of simulation are you doing? I would be able to help much better if you say which simulation you are doing.