# Settings to make viewport playback drop frames in order to keep up with actual animation speed?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, customization, performance, frame-rate

I'm animating a character in 24 fps, but my computer is only able to playback at 20fps at the most in this scene, so when I play the animation in the viewport it's actually much slower than it should be. This makes it harder to animate because I don't actually see the animation in the actual speed it should be in.

Of course I understand this is a technical thing: my computer is not capable of drawing 24 frames per second in this particular scene and nothing will change that. A work around is to hide other objects and simplify as much as possible so the computer can keep up with the frame rate.
But there's another possible solution that other softwares use (3ds Max, for exemple): to simply drop frames in order to keep up with the real animation speed. So even though the computer can't draw 24 frames per second, it draws as much as it can but skips a few frames as not to lag behind the "real speed" of the animation. This solution also has it's down sides, but in many cases it's better to drop frames than to preview the animation in 'slow motion'.

My question is: is there a setting somewhere in Blender that does that (makes the viewport playback drop frames to keep up with the 'real speed' of the animation)? Being able to toggle between the two modes (drop-frame or non-drop-frame) would be really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look on a timeline view.  There's a dropdown labelled "Playback".  If you click that, you'll get a pop-up menu.  In that menu, there's a field labelled "Sync".  Click in that field and select "Frame Dropping".

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you